# vaadin progressbar on grails 2.2.3 using grails-vaadin 7.1.8.2 plugin

Tags: grails, vaadin

I was trying to get the vaadin progressbar working on my grails/vaadin app, but couldn get the UI updated, I was reading about "vaadin push" but only found documentation about Java in this link   https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.push.html#advanced.push.running has anybody put this to work  on grails/vaadin plugin.

Thanks.

Edit after Ondrej suggestion:

I took the way of icepush included the jars in lib directory, created the pusher instance added the pusher instance to my main layout, called UI.getCurrent().pusher.push(), the only step I coudldn't make was changing the servlet.

the documentation says: **"We have to use org.vaadin.artur.icepush.ICEPushServlet instead of com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet"** I installed the templates to configure web.xml however there is no reference to VaadinServlet on It, neither in VaadinConfig.groovy.  when I run the app, shows this message **"Widgetset does not contain implementation for org.vaadin.artur.icepush.ICEPush. Check its component connector's @Connect mapping, widgetsets GWT module description file and re-compile your widgetset. In case you have downloaded a vaadin add-on package, you might want to refer to add-on instructions."**

I already compiled but still the same message, how can I change the servlet for IcePush in a vaadin/grails environment.

Comment: Maybe push won't be needed: I used thread to do the logic with progressbar as parameter and I updated progressbar in this thread.

Comment: Thanks dzezz for you reply, do you have any example,and wich version of plugin and grails were you using?, I already tried that on my project and didn't work, Ill try again to see if was something else, and Ill let you know.

Comment: I don't use grails, I expected this to be same as in Vaadin with java...

Comment: I looked at the code and there is no push implemented. I would say, the way how you do it, it won't never work. You really need to implement push from the link you have posted, or you can maybe use this Vaadin plugin https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/icepush

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should put

```
asyncSupported = true
```

into VaadinConfig.groovy (see more info [here](https://github.com/ondrej-kvasnovsky/grails-vaadin-plugin/blob/master/grails-vaadin7-plugin/src/samples/_VaadinConfig.template))

Also, change a property in BuildConfig.goovy from 2.5 to 3.0:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0"
```

Comment: Thanks Ondrej, I tried, however it didn't work, i downloaded vaadin-push-7.1.0.beta1.jar, and included it in lib directory, but tried to  include the @Push anotation on my UI class and didn't compiled.

Comment: Could you share a sample project simulating your issue, e.g. on github?

Comment: Hi Ondrej, this is the sample project https://github.com/fcastaneda/mposTest Thanks for your help

Comment: Please update to latest version. It has been fixed here: https://github.com/ondrej-kvasnovsky/grails-vaadin-plugin/commit/48050c521bff993654a44884ac2d15b2c58c8d84 and I forgot to post it here.